# adding coordinate to an onto linear map to obtain a bijection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^k$ be an onto linear map. Let $\beta: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^l$ be a linear map such that $(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^k\times \mathbb R^l $ is injective. Then there are $n-k$ coordinates in $\mathbb R^l$ such that $(\alpha,\beta_1\dots,\beta_{n-k})$ becomes a bijection.

My try: I know $(\alpha,\beta)$ is injective, therefore the columns of the representing matrix are independent. On the other hand, by surjectivity of $\alpha$, for every basis $B$, $\alpha(B)$ generates $\mathbb R^k$, and clearly $k\leq |\alpha(B)|\leq n$. But I can not make any reasoning to say there are $n-k$ coordinates in $ \mathbb R^l$ such that $(\alpha,\beta_1\dots,\beta_{n-k})$ becomes a bijection.

Comment: I'm assuming the question is asking for a bijection **with the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k\otimes \mathbb{R}^l$ spanned by the first $k$ vectors and the $n-k$ coordinates,** which has dimension $n$.

The rank nullity theorem tells us that the nullspace of $\alpha$ has rank $n-k$. Choose a basis for this and choose $n-k$ coordinates to make sure that these basis vectors for the nullspace of $\alpha$ are not sent to zero by the $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_{n-k}$. This gives injectivity, and surjectivity follows from dimensionality.

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{R}^k\times \mathbb{R}^l$, not $\otimes$, but it's been too long to edit my comment.

Comment: @user1237264 It helps, thanks!